# Every subset of a countable set is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In one textbook there is written:

*The elements of a countable set $S$ can be written down as a finite or an infinite sequcence $$a_1, a_2, ...$$ where repetitions are allowed. We call this an enumeration of $S$.*

So we have one-to-one map from the set $S$ to the subset of $\mathbb{N}$. There are not repetitions in $S$ because it is the set.

Question: How it is possible that there are repetitions in the enumeration of $S$? A simple example with finite set will be very helpfull.

Comment: Take $S=\{1,1\}$. Then $S$ is countable. Of course $S=\{1\}$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890609/why-the-set-1-is-equal-to-the-set-1-1-1-a-box-with-3-equal-element).

Comment: Any surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $S$ is an enumeration of $S$. It does not need to be one-to-one - elements are allowed to occur more than once in the sequence. All that matters is that every element does occur at least once.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Your first $S$ is a finite sequence or multiset or anything else but not is a set. I understand it. Now I have this strange $S=\{1(first), 1(second)\}$ and I want to construct a function to the set $K=\{1,2\}$. Now I know that a function is a one-to-one mapping from the set to the set. It is by the deffinition. If I say $1(first)=1$ and $1(second)=2$ then I get sequence with repetition (1,1). But but it is not possible because in this situation for exactly one element (1) I get two values ( 1 and 2). It is contradict the definition of function. Where is my problem?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Oh. I missed that this mapping from $\mathbb{N}$ to other set. Thanks

Comment: @Mokhmad-SalekhKhekhaev Yes, to any index $i\in \mathbb{N}$ you have an associated element $a_i \in S$, so this is essentially a map from $\mathbb{N}$ to $S$. At least, in the (countably) infinite case it is, but finite sequences are allowed too if $S$ happens to be finite.

Comment: You asked "How is is possible that there are repetitions in the numeration of $S$?" The sequence $a_n=(-1)^n$ is an enumeration with repetitions of the set $S = \{-1,+1\}$: the value $-1$ is repeated infinitely often (by all odd values of $n$); and the value $+1$ is also repeated infinitely often (by all even values of $n$).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Last question. I have three elements $A, B, C$. I want to enumerate them. You say that the enumeration is a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{A, B,C\}$. What I will do with natural numbers after 3? If enumeration is a function then it must be defined for all natural numbers.

Comment: As I wrote, finite sequences are allowed too when $S$ is finite. So you could just have an enumeration of length 3 such as $(A,B,C)$ or $(A,C,B)$, longer finite ones with repetitions like $(A,A,B,C,B)$ or $(C,B,B,B,B,A,B,C)$, or infinite ones such as $(A,B,C,A,C,A,A,A,...)$ where $a_i=A$ for all $i>5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the infinite sequence $1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,\dots$ which has elements from $S=\{1,2,3\}$.This list $1,2,3,1,2,\dots$ is what is meant by an enumeration of $S$. Hope this helps.